# startDrag() gets NullPointerException with first view when fixed size GridView Item

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception, drag-and-drop

I have a GridView. Each of the items in the GridView contain some ImageView and TextView. In the onLongPress() handler, I call the startDrag on the ImageView. Everything working ok without first item of gridView. I get the NullPointerExpception with it:

```
 E/View: Unable to initiate drag
 E/View: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.IWindowSession android.view.View$AttachInfo.mSession' on a null object reference
 E/View:     at android.view.View.startDrag(View.java:20983)
 E/View:     at com.abc.xyz.util.view.CustomGridView$1.onItemLongClick(ES.java:55)
 E/View:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3939)
 E/View:     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
 E/View:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 E/View:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 E/View:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
 E/View:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
 E/View:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 E/View:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
 E/View:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I was able to verify that all of the arguments passed to startDrag were non-null - a ClipData, a DragShadowBuilder, and my view as the LocalState. Here's that code snippet:

```
ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(((ABC) getItemAtPosition(position)).getUri());
String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
ClipData data = new ClipData("", mimeTypes, item);
data.addItem(new ClipData.Item(position + ""));
DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view.findViewById(R.id.img));
view.startDrag(data, // data to be dragged
        shadowBuilder, // drag shadow
        view, // local data about the drag and drop operation
        0 // no needed flags
);
```

I found that if set fixed size of GridView item in adapter, the issue will be occur.

```
     @Override
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = convertView;
         ...
         v.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams((int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.pp_item_w),
                     (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.pp_item_h)));
         return v; 
     }
```

So, what I can do in this case and keep fixed size of GridView item.

Answer (score 0):

I found that first item of my GridView also can not update view when invalidate().
I read some thread that it could be happening because of trying to access a view that has not been inflated yet. 
So, I found the solution for my code and keep set fixed size of GridView item. That is only set when convertView = null.

```
    @Override
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = convertView;
         ...
         if(v == null) {
               ...
               v.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams((int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.pp_item_w),
                     (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.pp_item_h)));
         } else {
               ...
         }
         return v; 
     }
```